# How to remove selected item from ListBox in windwos phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I want to delete selected item from listbox in widnows phone I have tryied

myclass is :

```
    public class mydata
    {
        public int text;

        public int Text
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

And my code which I bind to List is

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        lstd.Add(new mydata() { Text = i });
    }
    txt.ItemsSource = lstd;
```

I have write this code on selectionchanged event of listbox

```
txt.Items.Remove(txt.SelectedItem);
```

but it give an error **"Operation not supported on read-only collection."**

I have also try this one

```
 var item = lb.SelectedItem as mydata;
            lstd.Remove(item);
            txt.ItemsSource = lstd;
            txt.UpdateLayout();
```

Item is removed from lstd but can not update layout of listbox;

**I do not want to write this line after removing item from Listbox**

```
txt.ItemsSource = null;
```

Please help me to sort out this.

Thanx in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422378/listbox-operation-not-supported-on-read-only-collection may help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the class of your `listed` object is `List<mydata>`, then change it to `ObservableCollection<mydata>`, so the list box will be notified about changes in `lstd`.